# Did Lakshmi come out of Samudramanthanam in the Ramayana version?

Tags: ramayana, lakshmi, samudra-manthan

In the twitter feed of eminent Srivaishnavite lecturer/teacher Velukkudi Krishnan - somebody asked the above question.

Comment: No mention of Devi Lakshmi

Answer (score 1):

No.  Lakshmi is not mentioned in the Samudramanthanam episode in Valmiki Ramayana.

https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga45/bala_45_frame.htm

> Once in Krita era, oh, Rama, the sons of Lady Diti were extremely energetic, whereas the sons of her younger sister Lady Aditi were vigorous and highly righteous. [1-45-15]

> "Oh, tigerly-man, Rama, then those great-souls speculated as to 'how we can thrive without ageing, illness, and likewise without death.' [1-45-16]

> A thought occurred to those masterminds who were thinking on that matter clueing them up, 'we indeed can get elixir of life by churning the Milky Ocean.' [1-45-17]

> Deciding upon to churn the Milky Ocean then made Vasuki, Thousand-headed King of Snakes, as the churning rope and Mt. Mandara as stirrer, and those brothers whose energy is unlimited have started churning the Milky Ocean thoroughly. [1-45-18]

> After a thousand years, the Thousand-headed serpent Vaasuki, which is being used as churning rope, is incapacitated to bear the friction of churning and fanged the cliffs of Mt. Mandara. Thereby a great lot of venom is disgorged from the heads of that serpent Vaasuki, which venom on melting the rocks of Mt. Mandara became the holocaustic poison called haalaahala. [1-45-19]

> A lethal poison similar to inferno known as haalaahala has started to fulminate therefrom, by which whole universe of gods, non-gods and humans is burnt down. [1-45-20]

> The gods seeking shelter then approached Rudra, the Cardinal God, Endower of Solace, and who husbands all the created animals inclusive of human-animals, namely Shiva, and they prayed to him saying 'save, save us.' [1-45-21]

> This way while the gods are praying the Lord and God of Gods, namely Shiva, then handling his disc and conch-shell Vishnu has also revealed himself at that place. [1-45-22]

> And Vishnu smilingly spoke to wielder of trident Rudra, 'oh, god the best, whatever element that has emerged from the churning of Milk Ocean by gods, that shall belong to you, isn't it. By virtue of your position as the foremost god among gods, oh, omnicompetent god Shiva, you please accept this poison applying yourself to that position of foremost god, and deeming this poison, haalahala, as a foremost oblation to your godhood'. [1-45-23, 24]

> Saying so Vishnu, the best one among gods, has disappeared then and there only. And on observing the scare of gods and also on paying heed to the words of the Wielder of Bow called shaar~Nga, namely Vishnu, god Shiva gulped that lethal poison, haalaahala , as if it is ambrosia. [1-45-25, 26a]

> The god of gods Hara then left for his abode Kailash parting with other gods, and oh, Rama, the joy of Raghu's dynasty, the gods and non-gods have continued to churn the Milky Ocean. [1-45-26b, 27a]

> Now the loftiest mountain that is being used as stirrer, namely Mt. Mandara, has caved into the netherworld, thereby the gods along with gandharva-s have prayed to Madhusuudana, the other name of Vishnu. [1-45-27b, 28a]

> 'You alone are the recourse to all beings, especially to the dwellers in heavens, oh ambidextrous god Vishnu, you safeguard us, it will be apt of you elevate the mountain.' So prayed gods to Vishnu. [1-45-28b, 29a]

> Hearing the prayer of gods Vishnu, Hrisheekesha, the controller of senses, adopting the form of a tortoise and positioning the stirring Mt. Mandara on that tortoiseshell, he lay recumbent at the bottom of Milky Ocean as a base to the stirrer. [1-45-29b, 30a]

> Keshava then reached out his hand and grasped the mountaintop as he is the Cosmic-Soul, and thus staying amid gods that Supreme Person Vishnu participated in churning the ocean by holding the stirring mountain upright. [1-45-30b, 31a]

> After a thousand years of churning, then a male personality, an epitome of Life Sciences, namely aayurveda , a highly righteous soul, named Dhanvantari, has firstly surfaced with his arm-rest-stick and with his handy water-vessel, and then the remarkably elegant Apsara-s, angelic damsels, have emerged next to him from the Milky Ocean. [1-45-31b, 32]

> Choicest females have come out an elixir obtained on absolute churning of the waters of Milk Ocean, oh, best one among men, Rama, thereby that genera of females became Apsara-s. [1-45-33]

> Six hundred millions of such Apsara-s with amazing dazzle have emerged from the churning of Milky Ocean, oh, descendent of Kakutstha, and their maidservants who emerged along with them are innumerable. [1-45-34]

> Anybody either from gods or demons espoused them, and when none espoused them they are virtually reckoned as 'general-purpose' Apsara-females. [1-45-35]

> Oh, descendent of Raghu, then the heaven-sent damsel Vaaruni came up from Milky Ocean searching for her espousal, who is the daughter of Varuna, the Rain-god, and who incidentally is the presiding deity of hard liquors and also called as sura. [1-45-36]

> Oh, Rama, the sons of Diti, namely asuraa-s, have not espoused that daughter of Rain-god, but oh, brave Rama, the sons of Aditi on their part, namely sura-s, have espoused that impeccable Vaaruni. [1-45-37]

> Thereby the sons of Diti are called asuraa-s, and the sons of Aditi are called suraa-s, and gods are delighted and rejoiced on espousing Vaaruni. [1-45-38]

> Then a best horse called Ucchaishravaa has emerged, oh, Rama, the best among men, and then a gem of a jewel, called Kaustubha, and like that amrita, the Supreme ambrosial elixir of gods, have also emerged. [1-45-39]

> Owing to the dispute regarding the possession of that ambrosia, oh, Rama, then there chanced a rampant ethnic havoc, and then the sons of Aditi have havocked the sons of Diti. [1-45-40]

> All the asura-s and demons have come to one side against sura-s, and there occurred a very gruesome war which was perplexing to all the triad of universe viz., ethereal, real and surreal spheres. [1-45-41]

> When everything is wading into annihilation then that omnicompetent Vishnu swiftly impounded Amrita, the Divine Elixir, by assuming his illusory power of Mohini. [1-45-42]

> Whoever confronted that Eternal and Supreme Person, namely Vishnu, in that war, then Vishnu whose blaze is threefold as manifest in the sun, fire and lightning, has pulverised him. [1-45-43]

> In this horrendous war between the progeny of Diti, namely demons, and the progeny of Aditi, namely gods, the sons of Aditi being gods, have altogether massacred the demonic sons of Diti. [1-45-44]

> "On eliminating the demonic sons of Diti and on acquiring kingdom of heaven, that eliminator of enemy cities, namely Indra, happily ruled the worlds that are inclusive of sages and caarana-s." Thus Vishvamitra continued his narration about Vishaala city and its emergence. [1-45-45]